# WebView and ProgressBar not appearing

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar, android-progressbar, android-layout-weight

So guys. I have a problem, I am creating an application and while the webview is charged, appears a ProgressBar loading before the content, see my code. The problem is that when you start the app, there is a white activity in place of the webview w the ProgressBar not appear. Follows the code.

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        <WebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>


    </FrameLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```

NOW MY CLASS:
// CODE WebView

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.idestudos.com.br");
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
});


    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){

            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){

            ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });


}`
```

Comment: This is an English-only site; please [edit] your question to be written in English.

Comment: I edited the question!! Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root `FrameLayout` has height set to 0dp, i.e., `android:layout_height="0dp"`, but has weight set to 1, `android:layout_weight="1"`, are you sure if its inside a `LinearLayout`? If not change the height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` or something.

Also, you're setting the client twice.
`myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {...});` two times there in the code.

Do this instead.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        myWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the progressbar inside FrameLayout and FrameLayout below WebView so that the progressBar will stay on your screen even when you scroll through the WebView...

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

           <ProgressBar
               <!-- your progress bar here-->
             />

      </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```